# Nodejs resolve promise if execution not completed withing given time

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

```
 return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

 //some work goes here

resolve(true)

  });
```

With Settimeout

```
 return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

 //some work goes here

setTimeout(function() { resolve(true); }, 5000);

  });
```

With setTimeout it is waiting for 5 sec even though my task completed in 1 sec. my requirement is  if task complete within 5 sec then promise should resolve immediately else it will resolve at 5 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the timeout when your task completes normally :

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    let safetyTimeout = setTimeout(resolve, 5000);

    //some work goes here

    // When it's done :

    clearTimeout(safetyTimeout);
    resolve();
});
```

Comment: Does it have any impact if I will not use clearTimeout

Comment: Well if you don't, your Promise will resolve twice

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 setTimeout(function() { resolve(true); }, 5000);
 let result = await someworkDone();
 if (result) resolve(result);
});
```

Here points to note:

- **Specify 5s time before anyone work** (statement positing is very important)
- then get the other work done
- If your work completes before 5s sec resolve immediately, as above in example.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Thille answer is the best practice i think with the clearTimout.

Just cause i spended some time to write a piece a code for anyone to use, i post it, maybe it will help someone with their code experiments.

```
async function test() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("5 Seconds Passed");
    }, 5000);

    // Some work equivalent to
    someWork(3000, resolve);
  });
}

console.log(await test());

function someWork(time, resolve) {
  // Some work goes here.
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("WORK STILL RUNNING");
    resolve("INSIDE 2nd TIMEOUT");
  }, time);
}
```

Just don't forget to implement Jeremy Thille clearTimeout.

Comment: The Promise will resolve twice. You need to cancel the timeout if you want to prevent that.

Comment: Yes i understand it. I just posted it cause it's a ready code snippet if anyone wαnted to experiment with that question. I didn't include the clearTimeout just not to "steal" any praise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using **Promise.race**. The idea is in Promise.race we'll do our work and race the work promise against another promise that resolves in
a given time (let's say 10s for the below example),

```
// let's say I've to make a db connection within 10 seconds, else throw an error
const pool = await Promise.race(
    [
        poolPromise, // a db connection promise
        new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(
            () => {
                reject("can't establish connection within 10s")
            }, 10e3)
        )
    ]);
```